# angularjs not get data from woocommerce rest api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, authentication, woocommerce

Sorry to say I am new in REST-API and authentication.

I am writing an application on angularjs using yomen. I want to get data using woocommerce rest api from wordpress. I am working on my computer local node server

I have write my controller

```
    /*get the function from phpjs*/

function rawurlencode(str) {
        str = (str+'').toString();
        return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').
                                                                                       replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A');
    }
       var oauth = OAuth({
                consumer: {
                    public: 'ck_my_customer_key',
                    secret: 'cs_my_customer_secret'
                },
                signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
             });

             var request_data = {
                 url: 'http://biswas-stall.com/wc-api/v1/products',
                  method: 'GET',

              };


              var data = oauth.authorize(request_data);

              var url =rawurlencode(request_data.url) + "&" +
                          "oauth_consumer_key"+"%3D"+rawurlencode(data.oauth_consumer_key)+
                          "%26"+"oauth_nonce"+"%3D"+rawurlencode(data.oauth_nonce)+
                          "%26"+"oauth_signature_method"+"%3D"+rawurlencode(data.oauth_signature_method)+
                          "%26"+"oauth_timestamp"+"%3D"+rawurlencode(data.oauth_timestamp)+
                          "%26"+"oauth_signature"+"%3D"+rawurlencode(data.oauth_signature);

            $http.get(url).success(function(data) {

                console.log(data);
            })
```

I am using https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a  this library for my authentication.

I am getting 404 Not Found massage. What is my wrong. Can any one help me?

Comment: Did you try v3 instead of v1? Also try adding headers to your request, content-type.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried v3, but fail. as woocommerce documentation they did not said anything about header.

Comment: Try replacing the first `&` with `?` in the final request url.

Comment: Also could you please an explicit request to the url that is formed.